# How to check if /init starts /etc/inittab

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, busybox, panic, inittab

I have an embedded ARM system with processor AT91SAM9G45.

System consists of two components:

1. Linux kernel (4.14.79)
2. Busybox 1.29.3 as initramfs image.

I connect to the device using putty and connecting to serial port.

When kernel starts, everything goes fine. Kernel unpacks initramfs image, all files are found and listed (I see it by debug messages). But when it starts /init, log messages are:

```
Freeing unused kernel memory: 384K
This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
run_init_process BEFORE /init
run_init_process AFTER /init, result = 0
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004
```

/init is symlink to /bin/busybox. I tried to replace /init with /sbin/init, /bin/busybox, /linuxrc, but results are the same.

/etc/inittab file:

```
# Begin /etc/inittab

id::initdefault:

si::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rc S

#l0::wait:/etc/rc.d/init.d/rc 0
#l1::wait:/etc/rc.d/init.d/rc 1
#l2::wait:/etc/rc.d/init.d/rc 2
#l3::wait:/etc/rc.d/init.d/rc 3
#l4::wait:/etc/rc.d/init.d/rc 4
#l5::wait:/etc/rc.d/init.d/rc 5
#l6::wait:/etc/rc.d/init.d/rc 6

ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -r now

su::once:/sbin/sulogin

1::respawn:/sbin/getty ttyS1 115200
2::respawn:/sbin/getty ttyS2 115200
3::respawn:/sbin/getty ttyS3 115200
4::respawn:/sbin/getty ttyS4 115200
5::respawn:/sbin/getty ttyS5 115200
6::respawn:/sbin/getty ttyS6 115200

# End /etc/inittab
```

/etc/init.d/rcS file (this file is allowed to execute):

```
#!/bin/busybox sh
echo "Hello world!"
```

I don't know if even /init process starts parsing /etc/inittab or it falls before getting /etc/inittab by some reasons I cannot find out. Maybe there are 
some mistakes in my /etc/inittab and /etc/init.d/rcS files. Maybe there are some errors with terminal (/etc/init.d/rcS cannot write to stdout cause it's blocked, suspended, being used by another process and so on).

How to definitely get sured, that /etc/inittab is started?

Comment: I cross-compiled BusyBox and linux kernel with same CROSS_COMPILER option: `CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-` The linux kernel version is 4.14.79. If I open compiled busybox binary with F3 at Midnight Commander, I see: `/some/path/to/busybox/bin/busybox: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1(SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=921ca074aa7e285cb654d1d1d7acc0cc88c039of, stripped`. I suppose that I must compile busybox for GNU/Linux 4.14.79, but don't see the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. 
I see there is space between rc and S
`si::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rc S`

change it to

`si::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS`

let me know if it works.

Comment: I've tried without space. No, it does not work. Same result.

Comment: can you try passing kernel cmdline `single`

Comment: Passed `single`. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

> /init is symlink to /bin/busybox.

The typical **/init** file in an initramfs built by Buildroot that incorporates Busybox is a script of seven lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
# devtmpfs does not get automounted for initramfs
/bin/mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /dev
exec 0</dev/console
exec 1>/dev/console
exec 2>/dev/console
exec /sbin/init $*
```

Note the comment ("devtmpfs does not get automounted for initramfs") and the **mount** command for **/dev**.

It's **/sbin/init** (rather than **/init**) that is linked to **/bin/busybox**.

IOW without the proper setup of the **/dev** directory, userland has no I/O capabilty.
Only after devtmpfs has been mounted should the **init** program in **Busybox** be executed, which will then access **/etc/inittab**.

See [Is there a way to get Linux to treat an initramfs as the final root filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235281/is-there-a-way-to-get-linux-to-treat-an-initramfs-as-the-final-root-filesystem)
and
[Make CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT apply to initramfs/initmpfs](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9193529/)

Comment: Tried this, same result.

I though that I do not see messages as "Hello world!" because console is blocked, disabled and so on.

I tried another way to check if /init is executed. There is a simple program /hellos in initramfs image. And kernel can distinguish if file exists or not. I added a string "rm /hellos" to /init (and also to /etc/init.d/rcS) and added a code to kernel which starts /hellos after /init returns. If file exists, but cannot be executed, kernel returns -14. If file does not exists, kernel returns -2.

Comment: So after executing /init which contains "rm hellos", kernel trying to start /hellos and returns -14, that means that /hellos was not removed. So I made a conclusion that problem is in starting /bin/sh, it cannot be executed by some reasons. Maybe, 4.14.79 kernel can't execute binaries which are **ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0**

Comment: *"Tried this, same result"* -- Then you have multiple problems, and your question only describes one of them.  We can't solve problems that are not adequately described.